# Serverless move s3 bucket reference to Resources

Tags: serverless-framework

### Situation

It's pretty simple. I want to have more fine-tuned control of the s3 buckets created by serverless by managing them in the `Resources` section. I used to reference the bucket like this:

```
my-function:
    handler: src/functions/my-function.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: my-bucket-${opt:stage,self:provider.stage}
```

But now I want to reference it like this:

```
my-function:
    handler: src/functions/my-function.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:resources.Resources.MyBucket.Properties.BucketName}

...

Resources:
  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: my-bucket-${self:provider.stage}
```

My understanding is that this will allow me more configuration options, let me include the bucket in outputs, etc...

However, I get this error when deploying to my `dev` stage:

`MyBucket - my-bucket-dev already exists in stack <stack info>`

### Question

Is there a way I can make this syntax change in Serverless without it throwing an error? I also didn't want to use `existing: true` because I'll be deploying to stages where the bucket won't exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the Logical IDs for the bucket and lambda permission.

See this example taken from the docs:

```
functions:
  resize:
    handler: resize.handler
    events:
      - s3: photos

resources:
  Resources:
    S3BucketPhotos:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: my-custom-bucket-name
        # add additional custom bucket configuration here
    ResizeLambdaPermissionPhotosS3:
      Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
      Properties:
        FunctionName:
          'Fn::GetAtt':
            - ResizeLambdaFunction
            - Arn
        Principal: 's3.amazonaws.com'
        Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
        SourceAccount:
          Ref: AWS::AccountId
        SourceArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::my-custom-bucket-name'
```

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3#custom-bucket-configuration

Comment: That's the example I was looking at when I made the changes... what's the critical difference between that example and mine? Also I'm not sure of the definition of "logical id" - what is the logical id in my case?

Comment: "logical id" is the identifier of the resource in the stack. Serverless framework generates them using a naming convention, thus you must keep the same convention in order to override resources.
In your file the logical id for the bucket is `MyBucket`, but will be resolved by the framework to something liket `S3BucketMyBucketDev` (Dev is the stage)